# How to create and async/await-based semaphore in Swift like this one in JavaScript which uses Promise?

Tags: swift

This is a crude example to keep things short:

```
let unlockResolve = () => {}
async function semaphore() {
     await new Promise((resolve) => {
           unlockResolve = resolve
     })
}

async function stopAtTheRedLight() {
     await semaphore()
}

function unlocksSemaphore() {
     unlockResolve()
     unlockResolve  = () => {}
}

await stopAtTheRedLight()

// Somewhere else:
// [...]
unlocksSempahore()
```

**What is the equivalent async/await based Swift code?**

Comment: I didn't downvote, but mixing semaphores and async/await is ... not a great idea. I'm not as experienced in JS, but even there it feels fishy. Do you have a motivating use case that makes this more concrete? The fundamental issue is that waiting on a semaphore causes the thread to block. Swift Concurrency relies on a guarantee of forward progress: if things are stuck waiting, then you re-introduce the risk of deadlock. Further, if your code is executing in a `Task` scheduled by the cooperative threadpool, then blocking one of those threads severely hinders the system's performance.

Comment: There are only as many threads in the cooperative thread pool as your system has cores. If you have 8 cores, you'll only get 8 threads. If one of your tasks is scheduled on of those 8 threads, then waiting on a semaphore instantly drops your app's performance by 12.5%, and that's just with a single wait. You _can_ make the two worlds (DispatchSemaphore and Swift Concurrency) "play nice together" by dispatching out to a separate queue to call `wait()`, then resuming a continuation when it's done. But that still begs the question: y tho?

Comment: @Alexander I’m running it under @ MainActor (main thread, assert Thread.isMainThread). So far everything runs smoothly in the app and there’s no sign of blocking.

Comment: The whole point of a semaphore _IS_ to block. Your semaphore does nothing. If you deleted literally all of the code that's associated with it, you will see no change in the behaviour of the system.

Comment: @Alexander This is a non thread blocking semaphore, hence the async await stuff everywhere. Don;t know of another name for it. I am NOT looking to block the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
Came up with a locking library overnight, markup docs are TODO and are coming soon.

**https://github.com/oxygen/AsyncAwaitLock-Swift**

//////////////

```
import Foundation
import Dispatch
import PlaygroundSupport

@MainActor
class Example {
    private var continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Never>? = nil {
        didSet {
            assert(oldValue == nil || continuation == nil)
        }
    }
    
    // From Apple’s docs: The checked continuation offers detection of mis-use, 
     // and dropping the last reference to it, 
     // without having resumed it will trigger a warning. 
     // Resuming a continuation twice is also diagnosed and will cause a crash.
    deinit {
        continuation?.resume()
    }
    
    func waitOnSemaphore() async {
        await withCheckedContinuation { [self] continuation in
            assert(Thread.isMainThread)
            
            self.continuation = continuation
        }
    }
    
    func stopAtTheRedLight() async {
        await waitOnSemaphore()
    }
    
    func unlockSemaphoreAction() {
        print("Unlock sempahore.")
        
        let continuation = self.continuation
        self.continuation = nil
        
        continuation?.resume()
    }
    
    func run() async {
        print("Waiting at red light")
        await stopAtTheRedLight()
        print("Got a green and we're running again.")
    }
    
}

let intersection = Example()
Task {
    try! await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2_000_000_000)
        
    await intersection.unlockSemaphoreAction()        
}
await intersection.run()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

// Output:
// 
// Waiting at red light
// 
// Unlock sempahore.
// Got a green and we're running again.
```

Answer (score 1):

With regard to your own answer: A closure to resume the `Continuation` is not needed, just keep it it in a private property.

I *obliterated* the misleading occurrences of the term `semaphore` and replaced `asyncAfter` with the Swift Concurrency equivalent.

```
actor Example {
    private var continuation : CheckedContinuation<Void,Never>?
    
    func waitOnGreen() async {
        await withCheckedContinuation { self.continuation = $0 }
    }
    
    func stopAtTheRedLight() async {
        await waitOnGreen()
    }
    
    func turnGreenAction() {
        print("Clear the traffic")
        continuation?.resume()
        continuation = nil
    }
    
    func run() async {
        print("Waiting at red light")
        await stopAtTheRedLight()
        print("Got a green and we're running again.")
    }
}

let intersection = Example()
Task {
    try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
    await intersection.turnGreenAction()
}

await intersection.run()
```

Comment: What would be the best way to prevent accidentally calling .resume() twice in your example? Docs say it would crash the app: “Resuming a continuation twice is also diagnosed and will cause a crash.”

Comment: You can set the continuation explicitly to `nil` right after resuming it. A subsequent call will be suppressed due to *Optional Chaining*.

Comment: Yeah that would do the trick, and a continuation?.resume() in deinit because docs say it will trigger a warning otherwise (leak?). I’ve updated my example.

Comment: Actually **you** – the developer – can ensure that `turnGreenAction` is called at least once.

Comment: Yeah. But debugging an accidental call which crashes the app, especially in production, would be a absolutely gigantic pain in the 4ss. So I’d rather, me the developer, do some defensive coding like explained in the comment above and otherwise just print a warning for the misuse, if any. Especially since in this program turnGreenAction will definately be called many times over and over again.

Comment: But writing defensive code as a *don't-care* alibi is not what Swift stands for, no offense.

Comment: Swift means clarity, speed, simplicity. In which case setting to null is the clear winner over maintaining counters outside the class by the calling code (which could be more than one place in the app). So that’s precisely what Swift stands for.

Comment: Misunderstanding: I mean the *defensive* call in `deinit` which won't crash the app if `resume` has not been called.

Comment: You have to call resume in deinit if it was never resumed. continuation?.resume() is perfectly valid. So is continuation = nil. Docs say a warning will be issued otherwise (possibly because of some leak or other reasons).

Comment: We are talking about different things. Please read my comment about *the developer* again.

Comment: Yeah, but look at the OceanGate sub and the Titanic itself. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Randomly resuming a leaked continuation isn’t safe. It’s masking for a more fundamental issue, (think about it: the same error detection that the standard library uses to trigger the crash, they could just as easily written to just resume the continuation instead. It’s an intentional decision.)

Comment: @Alexander It is not leaked if you hold a reference to it. The docs clearly state to resume it before losing the reference so some cleanup code is absolutely necessary and also good practice. “and dropping the last reference to it, without having resumed it will trigger a warning” An observer to assert the continuation is nil (which means no unresumed continuation exists) in willSet is also needed here. I’ll update my own example.